# Conditional Multi-Line Grep Problem

Tags: regex, grep, multiline

I have a very large file I want to extract lines from. I'm hoping Grep can do the job, but I'm running into problems.

I want to return all lines that match a pattern. However, if the following line of a matched line contains the word "Raw" I want to return that line as well.

Is this doable?  Or would another method be more suitable?

For example,

Input:
pattern blah blah blah
something nothing
pattern something ready
nothing Raw

A grep on "pattern" should return:
pattern blah blah blah
pattern something ready
nothing Raw

The line "nothing Raw" is included in the results because it contains "Raw" and follows the already matched line "pattern something ready".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
grep -A 1 'pattern' file.txt | grep 'pattern\|Raw'
```

Comment: Does that work? If it does, it's awesome.

Comment: That's the magic of UNIX commands and the UNIX architecture. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29 ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's complaining about the second grep statement:

grep: Trailing backslash
'Raw'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @redbluefish: Have you put that argument in quotes?

Comment: @redbluefish: Maybe `pattern` contains more single quotes or other funky characters?

Comment: Maybe just show us the exact command you're trying to use.

Comment: Got it working with one tiny change:  double-quotes instead of single-quotes.  Thanks.  As an aside now that it works, how would I edit the command to deal with a scenario of a blank line between each line in the file?

Comment: To strip out blank lines, start the pipeline with: grep -Ev '^$'

Answer (score 0):

There might be some fiendishly clever way to do this with grep. But in the time it takes to think of that, you could have already written your script in Perl.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $pattern = 'pattern';
my $raw = 'Raw';
my $prevMatched = 0;
foreach my $ln (<>)
{
   if ($ln =~ /$pattern/)
   {
      print $ln;
      $prevMatched = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      if ($prevMatched && $ln =~ /$raw/)
      {
         print $ln;
      }
      $prevMatched = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many grep implementations supports -e which you can then chain:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -e "^<pattern>" -e "Raw"
```

(But that only works if every occurrence of "Raw" is valid)